# EFCore save entity with relation ids

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to save an entity, but this entity is related to another one and of this one I only have the id. For example, giving this structure:

```
public class Library
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int LibraryId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Bookshelf Bookshelf { get; set; }
}

public class Bookshelf
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

I receive from the client a new book to save to the db. This book only contains the `Title`, the `LibraryId` and the `BookshelfId` (it's a DTO).
Now I want to save this book, creating the relationship with Library and Bookshelf, without retrieving the full object `Library` and `Bookshelf`, how can I do it easily?

What if, for example, I want to create a new library, and relate it to some already existing books? What I should do to achieve it?

Comment: I would recommend you to create a reference to the Library object. Creating new property: public Library Library { get; set; } and fetch your Book using Including both the Library and Bookshelf. After that you update your entities and apply the changes needed. To create a new Library create a new instance of a Library object, add it to your Database (ContextDb) and set it to the new Book propery called Library and save the Book object with the changes.

Comment: Fetch the book? book in the first question is what i want to create, so I cannot fetch it. Also I'm hoping that the property `LibraryId` inside book would suffice without having to create the entiry property Library

Comment: Than I think this documentation can explain you what you can do with 'Saving Related Data'. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/related-data. Good luck.

Comment: Not really, I'm hoping that with the Id of the related entity I would be able to create the relationship. It's really strange that I need to retrieve the full object Library and Bookshelf and that I need to set them on the book.

Comment: Add the new library to your database: yourContextDb.Add(new Library { LibraryId = 1, Name = "New Library"}) and save your new book saving it with the new library's id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I want to save this book, creating the relationship with Library and Bookshelf, without retrieving the full object Library and Bookshelf*

Simply add a property BookshelfId on your book class.

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int LibraryId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Bookshelf Bookshelf { get; set; }
    public int BookshelfId { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
DbContext.Add(new Book { LibraryId = 1, BookshelfId = 1});
DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

*What if, for example, I want to create a new library, and relate it to some already existing books*

Add Library navigation property on the book

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Library Library { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

and then you can update the library property on the books using only their ids

```
var library = new Library { Name = "My library" };
DbContext.Libraries.Add(library);

var bookIds = new int[] {1, 2};

foreach(var bookId in bookIds) {
    var book = new Book { Id= bookId, Library = library};
    DbContext.Attach(book);
    DbContext.Entry(book).Property(b => b.LibraryId).IsModified = true;
}

DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: For the first one, i'll give it a try asap. For the second one, is there any way to do it without retrieving the books objects, but only with their ids?

Comment: The first one saved the entity with relation correctly for me. But when i get the book, BookshelfId is correct but Bookshelf is null.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Book` Model will slightly change to reflect the relationship with the `Library` and `BookShelf` Models

```
public class Book
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }

  public int LibraryId { get; set; }
  public Library Library {get;set;} //navigation property to Library

  public Bookshelf Bookshelf { get; set; }
  public Bookshelf Bookshelf {get;set;} //navigation property to Bookshelf
}
```

The way i see you write your model means : a `Book` cannot be created without a `Library` but a library can be created without a `Book`.

Comment: Yeah exactly, a book needs a library. But what of this? How do I save a new book, and relate it to an existing library, only knowing the libraryId, without fetching the whole library?

Answer (score 0):

This example I create a new library, new book shelf and new book without fetching any data.

My classes:

```
public class Library
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}

public class Bookshelf
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int LibraryId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public int BookshelfId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("BookshelfId")]
    public virtual Bookshelf Bookshelf { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("LibraryId")]
    public virtual Library Library { get; set; }
}
```

Saving new Book with new Library and new Bookshekf.

```
var contextDb = new LabContextDb();

var newLibrary = new Library()
{                
   Id = 1,
   Name = "My new library",
};

newLibrary = contextDb.Libraries.Add(newLibrary).Entity;

 var newBookshelf = new Bookshelf() { Id = 2, Color = "Blue" };

 newBookshelf = contextDb.Bookshelves.Add(newBookshelf).Entity;

 var newBook = new Book()
 {
    Id = 5,
    Title = "My New Book",
    LibraryId = newLibrary.Id,
    Bookshelf = newBookshelf
  };

 contextDb.Books.Add(newBook);
 contextDb.SaveChanges();
```

**Expected result**

[image]